# Узнать MAC адрес Android-устройства (в случае если это - планшет без GSM модуля)

Tags: android

Добрый вечер.

Вот так получаю IMEI (если есть GSM модуль):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.getDeviceId();
```

А если модуль отсутствует, я так понимаю, функция не сработает (IMEI-то нет)? Или что она вернет в этом случае?

Как в таком случае правильно задать условие и узнать MAC-адрес устройства, если оно без GSM модуля?

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**
В двух словах - как определить есть ли на устройстве GSM модуль?

Answer (score 1):

Может так

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddr = wifiInf.getMacAddress();
```

Comment: Под рукой нет планшета, но хочется правильно понять, что вернет tm.getDeviceId(); если приложение запускается на планшете, а уже потом какое написать условие чтобы (если нет IMEI, то узнать MAC)?